# Extend tab context menu of eclipse view part

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

In Eclipse 3.x the tab context menu of a viewpart had the actions "detached, restore, move, size, minimize, maximize".

I need to implement this functionality in my Eclipse e4 application (4.4). Is there a way to implement this using methods the framework offers me?
If not, what would be the best "starting point" to modify the framework itself without breaking the whole thing? I looked at the sourcecode of the class ViewPart but I'm not sure where I would have to put my code.

**EDIT**

I formulated my question wrong. My application is not an e4 application, but a migration from eclipse 3.0 to 4.4, without application model and other fancy new stuff.

Comment: ViewPart is a 3.x class and is not used in a pure e4 application.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to use a customized Stack Renderer for this (see [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4Renderer/article.html) for setting up renderers).

Your stack renderer can extend the standard `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer` renderer. You can override the method:

```
protected void populateTabMenu(final Menu menu, final MPart part)
```

to change the tab context menu.

Comment: This seems to work only if you use the application model of e4. My application is just an eclipse 3.0 application migrated to 4.4 without any of the new stuff, just bug fixes, because some stuff doesn't work right or just disappeared (like the context menu of a tab) in Eclipse 4.4

Comment: Then your app is not 'e4'. The stack renderer is still used for 3.x compatibility mode applications, so I think you should still be able to use this.